# inout-parameter - replace one const-handle with another

Tags: pointers, casting, d, const-correctness, const-cast

In an object, I have an array of const-handles to some object of another specific class. In a method, I may want to return one of this handles as an `inout`-parameter. Here as a simplified example:

```
class A {}

class B {
    const(A) a[];
    this() { 
        a = [new A(), new A(), new A()];
    }

    void assign_const(const(A)* value) const {
        // *value = a[0]; // fails with: Error: cannot modify const expression *value
    }
}
void main() {
    const(A) a;
    B b = new B();
    b.assign_const(&a);
    assert(a == b.a[0]); // fails .. obviously
}
```

I do not want to remove the const in the original array. Class `B` is meant as some kind of view onto a collection constant `A`-items. I'm new to D coming from C++. Do I have messed up with const-correctness in the D-way? I've tried several ways to get this to work but have no clue how to get it right.

How is the correct way to perform this lookup without "evil" casting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Casting away `const` and modifying an element is undefined behavior in D. Don't do it. Once something is `const`, it's `const`. If the element of an array is `const`, then it can't be changed. So, if you have `const(A)[]`, then you can append elements to the array (since it's the elements that are `const`, not the array itself), but you can't alter any of the elements in the array. It's the same with `immutable`. For instance, `string` is an alias for `immutable(char)[]`, which is why you can append to a `string`, but you can't alter any of its elements.

If you want an array of `const` objects where you can alter the elements in the array, you need another level of indirection. In the case of structs, you could use a pointer:

```
const(S)*[] arr;
```

but that won't work with classes, because if `C` is a class, then `C*` points to a reference to a class object, not to the object itself. For classes, you need to do

```
Rebindable!(const C) arr;
```

[Rebindable](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_typecons.html#Rebindable) is in std.typecons.

Comment: Casting away const were my last option even if it were defined behaviour. Before this, I had removed the const altogether. But it would have been ages, before I had found an acceptable solution with `Rebindable` (.. or at least days). Thank you!

Comment: It's the sort of thing you're probably only going to know about if you read an article which mentions it or an answer to a question like this. But due to how D's type system works, you pretty much have to have something like `Rebindable` to make a class `const` but not have its reference be `const` - the type system simply doesn't have any concept of the difference between the two. `Rebindable` solves the problem well enough, but since most people have trouble understanding why they can't do it in the language itself, it's not the sort of thing that most people will think of.